# Wrong DNG colors but correct JPG. How can I "transfer" correct colors to the DNG?

Tags: jpeg, dng

I have a Fimi X8 SE drone and it has a RAW DNG (+ JPG) capture mode.

The only downside to this is that the DNG files are somehow "broken" because all colors seems to be wrong. Strong magenta cast in the shadows, looks like green in the highlights, etc.

However, the JPG produced by the drone is perfectly normal.

My question is, is there a way to: either fix or correct the DNG colors, or somehow "transfer" the correct JPG colors onto the DNG file ?

I've put the images in the attachement.

Thanks in advance for anyone trying. Cordialy.

Here are the different RAW + JPG files for anyone wanted to try something: https://mega.nz/folder/0t1R3DxT#mk5tJszH-nZtTsqblTCeLA

Here are the different comparisons:

[image: Comparison #1]

[image: Comparison #2]

[image: Comparison #3]

Comment: You do no say what software you are using to look at or render an image from the RAW DNG files. Do you have software that is capable of editing RAW DNG files?  Is the camera's  software  producing the JPG files, how are you going to know what parameters the cameras software used to produce the JPG images?

Comment: *"How can I “transfer” correct colors to the DNG?*" You can not transfer colors to a DNG file. You need software that has the ability to edit RAW files and the experience to know how to use the software to make changes that  you feel are true to the original scene.  **If you like the JPG images then what are your plans for DNG files that will have  the "correct" colors?**

Comment: It would appear you're not alone in finding the dng files almost unusable - https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4376582#forum-post-62459752 However, there's a firmware update released just last week that *might* address this - https://www.fimi.com/fimi-x8-se.html - scroll to Download.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I'm sorry, I didn't put any software because I'm open to anything in order to fix these DNG. I used to edit on Lightroom but I'm switching to Darktable and if a solution is only available using LR, then I'm okay with it.
And I want to edit these images because I want to do it my way, + having a lot more flexibility the RAW images can offer.

Comment: @Tetsujin yup, it's a shame this problem isn't fixed yet...

Comment: @bmx22c *Something* used software to convert the monochrome luminance values in the DNG to a viewable color image for the examples you posted. [What you see on your screen when you view a "raw" file is not "THE raw file"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/100927/15871), it is one of countless possible interpretations of the raw data collected by the sensor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RAW files are supposed to be edited and color corrected, that's their purpose - it is a digital negative (dng). When you make it positive you have control on how it becomes positive image that we see. The 'transfer' happens from dng/RAW to jpg not the other way round.

Changes to raw files are non-destructive. Here are the things I did in your dng files to bring about the look (as much as I could) of your jpg files:

1. Color temp and tint
2. Shadows (pulled them up)
3. Saturation +28
4. Multiple changes in hue, saturation and luminance of red, orange, yellow, green, aqua and magenta
5. Some changes in Calibration

It appears that the RAW profile of your drone is seriously screwed up. High blue saturation in shadows and midtones, haze across the board (this could be either because of the natural haze or profile issue), color temperature in the highlights. That explains why you were upset with the dng files.

However they worked around this by building a smart/adaptive jpg conversion algorithm which is not straight forward - it is applying corrections selectively. Eg. dehaze is applied in midtones but not in highlights. The reason why you are okay with the jpg files.

I tried but couldn't replicate all these corrections by making global changes - it is possible with local adjustments though. The reason as you know is that I won't be able to create a preset if I make any local adjustments - so that's off the table.

Following differences are still there, but this was as close as I could get by using global adjustments only.

1. Red hue/saturation in the highlights
2. Green hue/saturation in the midtones
3. Selective de-haze (as you can see in the last image, when global dehaze is applied sky shows banding. It can be fixed by using selective local adjustments)

I created a preset with these settings, I can share the dng files with my corrections if you want.

I used Lightroom Classic v9.3 (latest) with Camera Raw v12.3

Cheers!

[image: IMG_20200626_194410_0299]

[image: IMG_20200626_194559_0301]

[image]

Comment: Hi @raviputcha thank you for this complete answer. I know that DNG are files that need to be corrected, but as you said, these are completely wrong. I "just" thought that maybe we could set the pixel value from JPG to DNG or something.
The haze present in the DNG are completely wrong, as the location I was shooting didn't had any.
You did an amazing job fixing these so thank you very much for that !
BUT, even with your explanations, I couln'd figured out how to do the same things. Can you share your preset with us please ?


Thank you again for taking your time.

Comment: Yeah, here's a link to download the preset: https://bit.ly/38lcxH8